# JavaScript Unsure What Code Does

Tags: javascript, css, function, class

The JavaScript below I am using in a login script but I would like to know exactly what this does.

```
$(function() {

    $('#login-form-link').click(function(e) {
        $("#login-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        $("#register-form").fadeOut(100);
        $('#register-form-link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();

    });

    $('#register-form-link').click(function(e) {
        $("#register-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        $("#login-form").fadeOut(100);
        $('#login-form-link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

I believe it has to do with css and maybe setting a css class active?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank's in advance!

Comment: it's jQuery - look up jQuery documentation at jQuery.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click the login link, it fades out the register form while it fades in the login form, then it gives the login form the active CSS class.

If you click the register link, it fades out the login form, while it fades in the register form, then it gives the register form the active CSS class.

In short, if you click log in the log in form shows up.  If you click register, the register form shows up.  It just does some animations and css class assignment too.

Answer (score 0):

```
// jQuery-way to wait until the document is has loaded
$(function() {

    // jQuery equivalence of "addEventListener" which binds a function 
    // (event-handler) to an element, which triggers when you click on said 
    // element (or children of that element, since events bubbles upwards)
    // You add it once, but it will trigger on EVERY click on the element
    $('#login-form-link').click(function(e) {  

        // jQuery way to show a hidden element with a fade-in animation.
        // Delay is added or else the following fadeOut will start early.
        $("#login-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);  

        // hide an elment, jquery
        $("#register-form").fadeOut(100); 

        // removes css-class, jquery
        $('#register-form-link').removeClass('active'); 

        // Adds a css-class, jquery
        // "this" in an event-handler refers to the element to which the
        // event-handler was added, so in this case: #login-form-link.
        $(this).addClass('active');

        // Prevents the default browser action for the event. 
        // For example, if the clicked element was a link, say
        // <a href="https://google.com">..</a> this would prevent 
        // the browser from loading up google.
        // If you don't have a href or use "" or "#" the browser might
        // refresh the current page or jump to the top of the page, 
        // in such cases you use the e.preventDefault to prevent that!
        // It's common to use with <a>-tags and it's not jQuery.
        e.preventDefault();

    });

});
```

"e" in this context is a [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) (not jquery).

Other than than, this is pretty much a hint for you to read up on jQuery. Have fun!